# problem with executing this code

Tags: jquery

I am new in jquery and Ajax.I want to send parameters with jquery to database with ajax.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#btnajax1").click(function(){
$("form").submit(function(event){
//event.preventDefault();
var user = $("input#tfuser").val();
var pass = $("input#tfpass").val();
if(!user)
{
    alert("user");
}
else if(!pass)
{

    alert("pass");
}
else
{
    $.post("files/forms.php",{username:user,password:pass},function(data)//line 36
    { 
        if(data == '1') alert("sabt shod");//line 40 
        else if(data == 0) alert("sabt nashod")//line 41


 else alert("can not connect"); //line 42
    })
}
return false;
    })
    })
}
);
```

in another page i have html file:

```
 <form id="form" action="#">
  <label>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </label>
  <label>
  user
  <input name="tfuser" type="text" id="tfuser" />
<p>
  <label>
  pass
  <input name="tfpass" type="text" id="tfpass" />
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
  <input name="btnajax1" type="submit" id="btnajax1" value="ajax user,pass" />
  </label>

</p>
<div id="result"> </div>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i click on ajax1 button on of 40,41,42 lines must runs.
my problem is that any of mentioned line doesn't run.
what is problem(i sure line36 is running)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {
        var user = $("input#tfuser").val();
        var pass = $("input#tfpass").val();
        if(!user) {
            alert("user");
        }
        else if(!pass) {
            alert("pass");
        }
        else {
            $.post('files/forms.php', { username: user, password: pass }, function(data) { 
                if (data == '1') {
                    alert("sabt shod");
                }
                else if (data == '0') {
                    alert("sabt nashod");
                }
                else {
                    alert("can not connect");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

You don't need to subscribe for the `.click` event of the button and `.submit` event of the form. The second is sufficient. Also when you are testing the `data` value from the server in your success callback you should compare it with the proper type as returned by the server and not use integer once and string the second `if`.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to hijack the click instead so you can preventDefault?  This will still submit the form right?

Comment: @kasdega, no I return `false` from the submit handler so it will prevent the default action.

Comment: i has following error: **Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative"  nsresult: "0x80570034 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_MODIFY_PROP_ON_WN)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/autocomplete.xml :: onxblpopuphiding :: line 848"  data: no]**

Comment: @mehdi, I don't see how this error can have any relation to the code.

Comment: in firefox ctrl + shift + j showed this but in my code there isn't this error

Comment: @Darin ah yep I see that now...You are correct.  I'd still grab the click instead.  I just prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do almost everything Darin suggested but I would grab the click instead so I could hijack the event and stop the form submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#btnajax1').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // you can also do a event.stopPropagation() if needed
        var user = $("input#tfuser").val();
        var pass = $("input#tfpass").val();
        if(!user) {
            alert("user");
        }
        else if(!pass) {
            alert("pass");
        }
        else {
            $.post('files/forms.php',{ username:user, password: pass},function(data) { 
                if(data == '1') {
                    alert("sabt shod");
                }
                else if(data == '0') {
                    alert("sabt nashod");
                }
                else {
                    alert("can not connect");
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also you could change the submit to a button which won't submit the form by default:

```
<input name="btnajax1" type="button" id="btnajax1" value="ajax user,pass" />
```

Comment: What if the user presses Enter while the focus is in the textbox? Using the .click instead of .submit will not intercept and handle this case.

Comment: @Darin excellent point and if that was a problem with my users I'd have to adapt and use your approach.